# Send Full HTML Mail with PHP

Tags: php, html, email

I would like to send an Email with PHP mail function but my HTML is being sent as plain text.

This is my code:

```html
$from    = 'admin@bla.com';
$headers = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $from . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" . 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$message = file_get_contents('cancelemail.php'); //Includes my HTML Page
```

thanks!

Comment: Instead of using `file_get_contents()` can you write your html code and assign it to `$message` as it is shown in this [example](https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)

Answer (score 1):

your headers should be array like:

```
$headers = array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8", "From: $from ");
```

Also, there is no point setting content as php file, content inside will be read as html, the  php code will not be executed;

Comment: I tried but it doesnt change anything. I still get plain text